# Magento - View localhost externally

Tags: magento, localhost, external

I am using ngrok to view my loclahost externally.

I can see the 'XAMPP for Windows' screen and it works great [see screenshot : http://i.imgur.com/UlNdIpG.png]. I can access everything on this screen.

However, when I type (MyAddress).ngrok/magento  I am 301 redirected to 127.0.0.1/magento and this does not work.

Any help on solving this issue is much appreciated. Or a work-around that allows me to view Magento from an external location would be great!

Answer (score 2):

You need change the URL on database.

On table core_config_data, find the values "web/secure/base_url" and "web/unsecure/base_url" on path column.

This will be 127.0.0.1/magento/

Replace the value by your URL (MyAddress).ngrok/magento

Comment: My base_url is http://localhost:1338/magento2x_6/, after i get the 2 urls from ngrok, what should i change in base_url, if i click on the ngrok provided url, it goes to xampp page, not my magento home page

Comment: @SachinS... what command did you use to run ngrok? Also try setting your base url to the value "{{base_url}}". That makes it work with any hostname, but must not be used in production, only development.

Comment: Thanks, its working now...My base url path was given properly as per ngrok